# How to call REST API using CURL in php?

Tags: php, json, rest, curl

I have problem when I am trying to call API using curl. My php code looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<body>
<span style="z-index:50;font-size:0.9em;">
<img src="https://theysaidso.com/branding/theysaidso.png" height="20"  width="20" alt="theysaidso.com"/>
<a href="https://theysaidso.com" title="Powered by quotes from   theysaidso.com" style="color: #9fcc25; margin-left: 4px; vertical-align:  middle;">
theysaidso.com</a></span>
<?php
       $service_url = 'http://quotes.rest/qod.json';
       $curl = curl_init($service_url);
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, false);
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
       $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
       curl_close($curl);
       $json_objekat=json_decode($curl_response);
       echo $json_objekat->contents->quotes->quote.'<br>';
       echo $json_objekat->contents->quotes->author.'<br>';    
?>
</body>
</head>
```

This code is saved as php file in my root directory on WAMP server. I use WAMP server. And it is written on this website  http://quotes.rest/qod.json that you must insert this html too. When I open this php page on WAMP it shows alert:

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$contents in
>   C:\wamp\www\IzdavackaKuca\javniServis.php on line 18
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\wamp\www\IzdavackaKuca\javniServis.php on line 18
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\wamp\www\IzdavackaKuca\javniServis.php on line 18
>
> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$contents in
>   C:\wamp\www\IzdavackaKuca\javniServis.php on line 19
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\wamp\www\IzdavackaKuca\javniServis.php on line 19
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\wamp\www\IzdavackaKuca\javniServis.php on line 19

JSON on this link http://quotes.rest/qod.json looks like this:

```
{
    "success": {
        "total": 1
    },
    "contents": {
        "quotes": [
            {
                "quote": "A loser doesn't know what he'll do if he loses, but talks about what he'll do if he wins, and a winner doesn't talk about what he'll do if he wins, but knows what he'll do if he loses.",
                "length": "184",
                "author": null,
                "tags": [
                    "failure",
                    "inspire",
                    "knowledge",
                    "winning"
                ],
                "category": "inspire",
                "date": "2016-05-11",
                "title": "Inspiring Quote of the day",
                "background":       "https://theysaidso.com/img/bgs/man_on_the_mountain.jpg",
                "id": "KhjRMynny89MKxcGkEKF_QeF"
             }
        ]
    }
}
```

When I change last two lines in php to this:

```
   echo $json_objekat['contents']['quotes']['quote'].'<br>';
   echo $json_objekat['contents']['quotes']['author'].'<br>';
```

it alerts:

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in
>   C:\wamp\www\IzdavackaKuca\javniServis.php on line 18

I realy don`t know how to call this server, when I code:

```
<?php
   $defaults = array(
        CURLOPT_URL             => 'http://quotes.rest/qod.json',
        CURLOPT_POST            => false,
        CURLOPT_HEADER          => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => false,
    );
    $curl               = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, $defaults);
    $curl_response      = curl_exec($curl);
    $json_objekat       = json_decode($curl_response);

    // DUMP THE CURL-ERROR INFORMATION:
    var_dump(curl_error($curl));
    curl_close($curl);
?>
```

it alerts:

> string '' (length=0)

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you are accesing quote and author incorrectly.
Output of `print_r($json_objekat)` says that:

> **contents** is stdClass Object
>   **quotes** is array
>   again quotes is having
>   **0** as index which is again stdClass Object

So, try accessing quote and author as follows:

```
$json_objekat->contents->quotes[0]->quote

$json_objekat->contents->quotes[0]->author
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming this is what you intend to do:

```
    <?php
        $service_url     = 'http://quotes.rest/qod.json';
        $curl            = curl_init($service_url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        $curl_response   = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        $json_objekat    = json_decode($curl_response);
        $quotes          = $json_objekat->contents->quotes;

        foreach($quotes as $intKey=>$objQuote){
            echo $objQuote->title       . '<br>';
            echo $objQuote->author      . '<br>';
            echo $objQuote->quote       . '<br>';
            echo $objQuote->background  . '<br>';
        }
    ?>
```

But be aware that you cannot make more than 10 Request per Hour using the same IP Address. 
So once you make up to 10 Requests, you'd be blocked and you have to wait for another 1 Hour to continue with your Requests.
Hope this helps......

Comment: This works also just like this answer from Suyog. Thank you so muck!

Comment: Just this bracket after  $quotes = $json_objekat->contents->quotes is redundant. Thats mistake, I know...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mydatabase");

if(!$conn){
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if(!function_exists("curl_init")) die("cURL extension is not installed");
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/ketan/all_user.php");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $result;
//print_r(json_decode($result));//To Decode Result
?>
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C6oB.png)

[image: Output]

all_user.php

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mydatabase");

if(!$conn){
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM tblUser");

$data = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    /*$result = array();
    $result['userId'] = $row['userId'];
    $result['firstName'] = $row['firstName'];
    $result['lastName'] = $row['lastName'];*/
    array_push($data, array('userId'=> $row['userId'],'firstName'=> $row['firstName'], 'lastName'=>$row['lastName'],
        'email'=>$row['email'], 'phoneNumber'=>$row['phoneNumber'], 'userImage'=>"user_images/".$row['userImage']));
}


$return['status']  = true;
$return['message'] = 'Success';
$return['data']    = $data;
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($return, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
$conn->close();

?>
```